# How to return PostgreSQL integers as Ruby integers, not strings?

Tags: ruby, arrays, postgresql

I have an array like this:

```
chats = [
  ["1", "First 1 Last 1", "3 -> 1", "1394994921"],
  ["2", "First 2 Last 2", "2 -> 3", "1394994921"]
]
```

It's the response from [`PGresult#values`](http://deveiate.org/code/pg/PGresult.html#method-i-values-doc). Why are the first & last elements in each row returned as `String`s in Ruby when they are actually `bigint` & `integer` (respectively) in PostgreSQL? How do I get them to be `Fixnum`s in Ruby?

I want:

```
chats = [
  [1, "First 1 Last 1", "3 -> 1", 1394994921],
  [2, "First 2 Last 2", "2 -> 3", 1394994921]
]
```

Comment: *How do I get them to be Fixnums in Ruby?* - is easy. You need to apply `#to_i`, on those first and last element.

Comment: *Why are the first & last elements in each row returned as Strings in Ruby when they are actually bigint & integer (respectively) in PostgreSQL?* - May be source data is like that, that's why.

Comment: The question is how to get PG to return proper values, not how to patch that over afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

Try enabling basic type casting with:

```
conn.type_map_for_results = PG::BasicTypeMapForResults.new(conn)
```

Source: [ruby-pg README.md: Type Casts](https://github.com/ged/ruby-pg#type-casts)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the postgres wire format always transfers values as strings, and has no easy way (i.e. no extra roundtrips) to find out the actual data type, so the client library returns everything as strings.

So:

```
def psql_fix_int_field_stupidity(res,fields)
  res.map do |row|
    fields.each do |f|
      row[f]=row[f].to_i
    end
    row
  end
end
```

That function can be used to halfways-generically patch result sets:

```
psql_fix_int_field_stupidity(conn.exec( "SELECT * FROM product" ), %W< id, parent >)
```

But you still need to know the column names.

Answer (score 0):

```
chats.each {|x| x[0] = x[0].to_i; x[-1] = x[-1].to_i}
```